auto screen rotation selection on HP X2 detachable losted after instalation
I have an HP X2 detachable and I'am trying to install Linux on it. Before the installation there is a choice in right-up corner : Auto rotate.
After the installation this choice is gone. I made this workable script but I'am searching for a better solution:
#!/bin/bash

monitor-sensor | while read -r line
do
    ORIENTATION=`echo $line | grep 'Accelerometer orientation changed:' | awk '{print $4}'`
    if [ -n "$ORIENTATION" ]; then
        echo "Detected orientation: $ORIENTATION"  # Εκτύπωση της τιμής του ORIENTATION
        if [ "$ORIENTATION" == "normal" ]; then
            xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate normal
        elif [ "$ORIENTATION" == "left-up" ]; then
            xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate left
        elif [ "$ORIENTATION" == "right-up" ]; then
            xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate right
        elif [ "$ORIENTATION" == "bottom-up" ]; then
            xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate inverted
        fi
    fi
done

